# How to get a list of required plugins for a Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have a small Jenkins instance running for years and over time a ton of Plugins got installed. I want to remove plugins that are no longer required by any jobs. Some of these jobs are "old" Freestyle jobs and some are Pipeline jobs with a Jenkinsfile.

Is there a way to list plugins which are required to build a job?